# Creating dynamic resources in flask restful and performing crud operations

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask-restful

I am creating a rest-api in python flask-restful that will take the string argument( 'Retailer' for example) and automatically generate the crud template for it on attribute id. Retailer has some more attributes that I have migrated using ORM. Now I need to take the class name 'Retailer' which is of type str and convert it into a resource and auto generate crud. My code is below.

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    from flask import Flask,jsonify
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
    import parse_json
    import create_models

    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)

    temp = parse_json.class_name

    def get(self,id):
        #code to be written here

    vars()[temp] = type(temp,(Resource,),{'get' : get})

    api.add_resource(vars()[temp], '/{0}/<int:id>'.format(temp))

    app.run(port = 5000)
```

I have created only the get method on this resource and dont know what to write in it to get all the attributes by its id. Please help !

Comment: just call your function that handle your selected request

Comment: I am dynamically adding the get method to this resource. This is where the request is being handeled.

Comment: call you model handler using id as parameter

Answer (score 0):

i i well understand, for example to retrieve data from your db according to a selected id

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dataset where id='"+id+"'")
data = cur.fetchall()
```